# Get First and Last Day of Any Year

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm currently trying to get the first and last day of any year.  I have data from 1950 and I want to get the first day of the year in the dataset to the last day of the year in the dataset (note that the last day of the year might not be December 31rst and same with the first day of the year).

Initially I thought I could use a `CTE` and call `DATEPART` with the day of the year selection, but this wouldn't partition appropriately.  I also tried a `CTE` self-join, but since the last day or first day of the year might be different, this also yields inaccurate results.

For instance, using the below actually generates some `MIN`s in the `MAX` and vice versa, though in theory it should only grab the `MAX` date for the year and the `MIN` date for the year:

```
;WITH CT AS(
    SELECT Points
        , Date
        , DATEPART(DY,Date) DA
    FROM Table
    WHERE DATEPART(DY,Date) BETWEEN 363 AND 366
        OR DATEPART(DY,Date) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
)
SELECT MIN(c.Date) MinYear
    , MAX(c.Date) MaxYear
FROM CT c
GROUP BY YEAR(c.Date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should refrain from developing in the evenings because I solved it, and it's actually quite simple:

```
SELECT MIN(Date)
    , MAX(Date)
FROM Table
GROUP BY YEAR(Date)
```

I can put these values into a `CTE` and then `JOIN` on the dates and get what I need:

```
;WITH CT AS(
    SELECT MIN(Date) Mi
        , MAX(Date) Ma
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY YEAR(Date)
)
SELECT c.Mi
    , m.Points
    , c.Ma
    , f.Points
FROM CT c
    INNER JOIN Table m ON c.Mi = m.Date
    INNER JOIN Table f ON c.Ma = f.Date
```

Answer (score 5):

You want something like this for the first day of the year:

```
dateadd(year, datediff(year,0, c.Date), 0)
```

and this for the last day of the year:

```
--first day of next year -1
dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(year, datediff(year,0, c.Date) + 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

`try this`

for getting first day ,last day of the year && firstofthe next_year

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0) AS Start_Of_Year,
 dateadd(yy, datediff(yy,-1, getdate()), -1) AS Last_Day_Of_Year,
   DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()) + 1, 0) AS FirstOf_the_NextYear
```

so putting this in your query

```
;WITH CT AS(
    SELECT Points
        , Date
        , DATEPART(DY,Date) DA
    FROM Table

WHERE DATEPART(DY,Date) BETWEEN 
DATEPART(day,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)) AND  
DATEPART(day,dateadd(yy, datediff(yy,-1, getdate()), -1))
)

SELECT MIN(c.Date) MinYear
    , MAX(c.Date) MaxYear
FROM CT c
GROUP BY YEAR(c.Date)
```

Comment: it is not the best example you are using, you will exclude all dates higher than year-12-31 and lower than (year+1)-01-01. You can improve the search for the end of the year slightly this way: dateadd(yy, datediff(yy,-1, getdate()), -1)

Comment: You are still missing the last day of the year. Between is not a good solution for datetime intervals. Even if you add one day you risk getting an extra row from the next year (2014-01-01 00:00:00.000)